# An average value for each item

Tags: python, pandas

It's required to find the average time of all delays time for each flight. Negative values should not be taken into account. How it's possible to do?

Dataset:

```
FlightNum ArrDelay DepDelay
1 10 14
1 -3 0
2 20 13
2 14 15
3 -3 -1
3 2 1
3 -10 -3
4 1 -2
4 11 9
5 10 8
5 20 11
5 -4 -1
```

Solution (by hands):

```
1: (10+14) / 2 = 12
2: (20+13+14+15) / 2 = 31
3: (2+1) / 3 = 0.66
4: (1+11+9) / 2 = 10.5
5: (10+8+20+11) / 3 = 16.3
```

The final result should be:

```
FlightNum AverageAllDelay
2 31
5 16.3
1 12
4 10.5
3 0.66
```

Tools: Pandas, Python.

Dataset (for your comfort):

```
data = {'FlightNum': {0: '1', 1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '2', 4: '3', 
                 5: '3', 6: '3', 7: '4', 8: '4', 9: '5', 
                 10: '5', 11: '5'}, 
        'ArrDelay': {0: 10, 1: -3, 2: 20, 3: 14, 4: -3, 5: 2, 6: -10, 7: 1, 8: 11, 
                9: 10, 10: 20, 11: -4}, 
        'DepDelay': {0: 14, 1: 0, 2: 13, 3: 15, 4: -1, 5: 1, 6: -3, 7: -2, 8: 9, 
                9: 8, 10: 11, 11: -1}}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: `(20+13+14+15) / 2 = 31` and not `24.5`

Comment: onyambu, yes, it was a mistake, I changed. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.mask`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) to mask the negative values then [**`pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) to calculate the mean.

```
out = (
        df.mask(df.lt(0), 0)
          .assign(AverageAllDelay= lambda x: x['ArrDelay'].add(x['DepDelay']))
          .groupby('FlightNum', as_index=False)['AverageAllDelay'].mean()
        )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

   FlightNum  AverageAllDelay
0          1        12.000000
1          2        31.000000
2          3         1.000000
3          4        10.500000
4          5        16.666667
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` to `sum` only positive values and then `sort`

```
(df.groupby('FlightNum').agg(lambda x: x[x>0].sum()/x.count())
   .sum(1).sort_values(ascending =False).reset_index())

  FlightNum          0
0         2  31.000000
1         5  16.333333
2         1  12.000000
3         4  10.500000
4         3   1.000000
```